# Transform scale not working with vue transition

Tags: vue.js

Using Vue transitions, fade works nicely, though trying to use `transform: scale(0)` doesn't seem to be happening and causes fade to no longer work. Any ideas?

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
    transform-origin: center center;
  }
  .fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
```

Modal

```
<transition appear name="fade">
    <div class="relative z-50" aria-labelledby="modal-title" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" @click="$emit('close-modal')">
      Test Div
    </div>
</transition>
```

Thanks

Comment: Just ran into a similar issue while using in <Transition> the Tailwind class ".scale-125" which applies "--transform-scale-x: 1.25;" and "--transform-scale-y: 1.25;". Made my own class instead using "transform: scale(1.25);" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0) rotate(-180deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
.rotate-enter-active {
  animation: rotate 0.2s;
}
.rotate-leave-active {
  animation: rotate 0.2s reverse;
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="main-content">
    <transition name="rotate">
      <img v-if="show" src="../img/logo.png" />
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).